# How to provide more value from test automation to Dev/entire team?

Tags: automated-testing, api-testing, qa-developer, uiautomation, sdet

Working primarily as UI test automation engineer, what further steps one should take to be more valuable & useful to the Dev team.

How one take automation to a level where it becomes an handy tool for testing for the entire team , not just the QA?

Edit: **I am looking for more practical examples where one solved an real problem using automation in such an unconventional way in his/her project ,and was well received by the entire team and actually proved helpful.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test automation is more than automating tests.

I recommend you reading [James Bach "Agile Test Automation"](http://www.satisfice.com/presentations/agileauto.pdf) article:

> Test automation progresses when supported by dedicated
>   programmers (toolsmiths).
>
> Toolsmiths are directed by testers.

Tools generated by toolsmiths might be useful for

> - **Test generation** (data and script generators). Tools might create specialized: data such as randomized email messages, or
>     populate databases, or generate combinations of parameters that we’d
>     like to cover with our tests.
> - **System configuration.** Tools might preserve or reproduce system    parameters, set systems to a particular state, or create or restore
>     “ghosted” disk drives.
> - **Simulators.** Tools might simulate sub-systems or environmental    conditions that are not available (or not yet available) for testing, 
>     or are too expensive to provide live on demand.
> - **Test execution (harnesses and test scripts).** Tools might operate the    software itself, either simulating a user working
>     through the GUI, or    bypassing the GUI and using an alternative
>     testable interface.
> - **Probes.** Tools might make visible what would otherwise be invisible    to humans. T hey might statically analyze a product,
>     parse a log    file, or monitor system parameters.
> - **Oracles.** An oracle is any mechanism by which we detect failure or    success. Tools might automatically detect certain kinds of error
>     conditions in a product.
> - **Activity recording & coverage analysis.** Tools might watch testing as    it happens and retrospectively report what was and was
>     not tested.    They might record actions for later replay in other
>     tests.
> - **Test management.** Tools might record test results; organize test    ideas or metrics.

In Agile teams such tools can be used by both testers and devs.

Answer (score 3):

To make it valuable for the entire team I would suggest to:

- Integrate your tests into **CI process**. So you need to take a role of devops or help your devops to do that
- Design your tests in **BDD style** (however not all the tests are ideally suitable for that) so that they are understandable by all the team and analysts or business users could take part in test design
- Integrate reporting framework and design your tests in the way that allows to compile **several types of reports** for the same test run with different level of details and with **emphasizing different aspects and metrics** depending on the target audience (test manager, project manager, product owner, etc.)
- Introduce the **documentation for your test code**. That will allow other people to easily add tests or maintain existing tests

Answer (score 3):

As a QA, things I implemented and now giving benefits for the entire team are:

**Test Data generation** - Devs and Users had less amount of test data in thier specific environments. We were not allowed to restore the data from Prod because it had client sensitive data. So I have learned and introduced a test data generation tool - *Genrocket* which generates necessary test data.

**Environment status** - our team had more than one Dev, Test and Prd servers. I have created a monitoring tool which checks and report the health of the application with the combination of *RestAssured* and *Selenium*. This eventually helped team to maintain an up and running application across all environments.